# react-native run-android :app:installDebug failed

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I created a react native application `react-native init AwesomeProject` in Windows8.
I have Genymotion 2.6.0 installed, with a Google Nexus 7.0 image working in the emulator.
I start the server `react-native start`.
When I run `react-native run-android` I get this error:

```
D:\react\AwesomeProject> react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug)...
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
...
:app:installDebug
10:47:59 E/ddms: 'C:\eclipse\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server'failed -- run manually if necessary                                                                                                     :app:installDebug                                                                   FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: Timeout getting device list.
```

The same happens with an AVD device (always on Windows8).
 Everything works fine instead on my iBook...

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered with the same issue on Windows 10.
Also my GenyMotion ADB setting was `Use custom Android SDK tools`.

When I run the command of `adb devices` I could see the device as connected.

Then I restarted the pc and it has been resolved.

Comment: It worked for me when I changed the GenyMotion settings to use my local SDL and pointing it to C:\Users\[MY_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Answer (score 1):

the error seems like it cannot get the device list.

if you can use shell. try the follow cmdline in the shell.

```
avd devices
```

the avd is a cmd tools under the android-sdk/platform-tools.

see detail on the google help page. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: Running `adb devices` gives `adb server is out of date.  killing...
    ADB server didn't ACK
    * failed to start daemon *
error:`<br>Running adbfix.exe shows `adb is up to date`.

Comment: I updated the android sdk. `adb device` now finds the device and the application is started in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In AVD you have to select an intelx86 atom image for your emulator or ADB won't connect to it for some reason.

You may have to install it in the android package manager in order to use it.

I had to.

Also check out this tutorial. It really helped me get everything up and running.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnqyUnASuk8

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did not have enough space on my device(emulator) to install the app, so I cleared up some space and tried again